# How to calculate space requirements for Team Foundation Server database

Tags: tfs

We're about to deploy TFS 2012 - mainly for source control at this stage but will hopefully ultimately provide a full work-flow for us.

Can anybody point me towards a sizing guide for the database aspect ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "how long is a piece of string?".

To qualify that short answer a bit, there is obviously an overhead to begin with.  TFS is much better than SourceSafe in that only changes are stored, so you don't get a different version of the file in the database for each check-in.  This is a good thing.

That said the answer to this question really depends on how often you're going to be checking in, the amount of changes there are between those check-ins and the overall size of all the projects and their related files.

To give you *some* metric, on our TFS server, the supporting TFS databases plus our "collection" database which has been running for 6 months now, with regular daily check-ins, is hitting 800mb.

Now, unless you head a *massive* project, I can't see you going over a half a TB anytime soon.  That said, given that TFS is SQL Server based - should you need to upgrade in the future it's not as much of a nightmare as you may think.

Comment: Thanks - it's just "vague" metrics I'm after as I know the DB guys are going to ask me the question on Monday !
To give some idea of the project we have around 4000 .vb files across 50 projects that make up our solution totalling around 70mb. We plan to add the database schema in there as well (looks to be around 1000 sys.objects and any stored procs / functions are quite small as well) so nothing major there. 
I'm just aware that once we start using the TFS side rather than the source control side that dropping screen shots etc., in can take it's toll !

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Fewer than 250 users: 1 disk at 7.2k rpm (125 GB)
>
> 250 to 500 users: 1 disk at 10k rpm (300 GB)
>
> 500 to 2,200 users: 1 disk at 7.2k rpm (500 GB)
>
> 2,200 to 3,600 users:1 disk at 7.2k rpm (500 GB)

However, as Moo-Juice said, the real-world numbers are dependent on how you actually use TFS.

Also keep in mind that you'll want to also create, store, and maintain **backups** of your TFS databases.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had looked at that and took that to more be about the "base" install rather than the additional files to control. 
The database will be onto a cluster and the dbas will be managing the back-up side for us.

Comment: @AndyMacnaughton-Jones I have a client with around 10 gigs of source controlled data (code, some huge PDFs for some reason, etc), and their 10+ year history is only around 100 gigs. If you're really paranoid, 500 gigs is fine to start with. You can always expand later.